# Where is the actual turtorial to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I hope this is the right place to ask (I didn't see any suitable stack overflow site that is feet perfactly to my question. If it's not the right place I am sorry and what SOF site is good to that question?)

I want to read [this](https://developer.android.com/courses/fundamentals-training/overview-v2) Android Studio tutorial. But all I see is the overview of the tutorial and I can't find the actual tutorial. I have started reading the previous version of the tutrial (it is [here](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/en/Unit%201/11_p_hello_world.html#task2intro)), but there is a warning message that says that the previous version is about to be deleted and they are recommand to read the new version.

How can I find the actual new version?

Comment: Nope. Wrong place: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I looked at all of the references in the overview but I can't find the actual tutorial.